# extracting a parameter using regexp

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, netezza

I have the data like

```
U=ms&sv1=5xdUE3w0&sv2=3150912100&sv3=kuqd1nwca0&sv4= altima
U=ms&sv1=5xdUE3w0&sv2=3150912100&sv3=kuqd1nwca0&sv4= altima_dhfdbf&
U=ms&sv1=5xdUE3w0&sv2=3150912100&sv3=kuqd1nwca0&sv4= altima&ddhfy6574dfx
```

when i use `('date','sv4=(.*?)[_|&]',1,2)` i am able to get from last two only, 
then i need to use this `('data','sv4=(.*?)$',1,2)` for remaining data.

Now I need to handle all these at a time.

```
O/P : altima  from all the above data.
```

please suggest on this, how to handle.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What part of the string do you want to extract? Not very clear from the question.

Comment: wt ever it is after sv4= and upto _ or &.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
sv4=(.*?)(?:[_&]|$)
```

Note that you don't need `|` in character classes to designate 'OR'.

I'm not sure if non-capture groups are available in oracle though and can't test it. But this would work otherwise in python, c#, php, etc.

Comment: it's working exactly. can you please explain this (?:[_&]|$). i did't understand exactly..

Comment: `(?: ... )` is a non-capture group. It's a group just like `( ... )` except that it doesn't 'save' the match. Now in the inside, you have `[_&]|$` which means `[_&]` or `$`. And `[_&]` means either `_` or `&`, while you already know what `$` does :)

Comment: Thx Jerry. initially i did't understand (?:) any how thx once again :)

Comment: Non-capture groups are NOT available in Oracle

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Huh, that's strange if the OP was able to use it the, because it wouldn't match at all for the last two instances provided. I admit I don't know Oracle as much as I want to, but how do you access captured groups? If you can indicate which of the 1st or 2nd capture group, using one shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Jerry - Last `1` in Ramblin' Man's answer is exactly the index of capture group.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks! Though I wonder why you didn't upvote his answer if it's a better answer than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
regexp_substr(string,'sv4= (.*?)(_|&|$)',1,1,'i',1)
```

The last parameter 1, to extract only first subexpression.